# SMTP Mandrill Port 587 Unable to connect to mail server: Connection timed out

Tags: php, email, smtp, port, mandrill

I have send e-mails for myself using Mandrillapp's SMTP server. It's not work show the MSG connection have timed out.

> Unable to connect to mail server: Connection refused(111)

SMTP Hostname: smtp.mandrillapp.com

SMTP Username: example@gmail.com

SMTP Password: API KEY

SMTP Port :587

i also used this other port like : 25,2525 
but not worked and show the same msg

> Unable to connect to mail server: Connection timed out(110)

any one can help me...

Comment: smtp.mandrillapp.com port 25 opened for me as did port 587.  Perhaps you should make your DNS is working and that you are not trying to connect to some other host.

Comment: Check your internet connection. Check your firewall rules.

Comment: Some shared hosting providers block all outbound SMTP connections. Which hostings you are using for testing of this. Contact to hosting provider to enable the connection or you need to switch your code on something other place if hosting did not support.

Comment: thanks for your help....